# In Rust, how can a JSON be deserialized in multiple structs?

Tags: json, rust, serde

Lets' say we have the following JSON:

```
{
   name:"John",
   age:"30"
}
```

and the two following structs:

```
struct Name {
   name: String;
}

struct Age {
   age: i32
}
```

What would be an efficient way to deserialize this JSON into this structs?

Comment: Create a third `struct Container { name: name, age: age }` and use `#[serde(flatten)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a third struct containing each of the others and use `#[serde(flatten)]` to deserialize each field as if it's a single flat struct:

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Name {
    name: String,
}
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Age {
    age: i32,
}
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Person {
    #[serde(flatten)]
    name: Name,
    #[serde(flatten)]
    age: Age,
}

fn main() {
    dbg!(serde_json::from_str::<Person>(r#"{ "name": "John", "age": 30 }"#).unwrap());
    // Person {
    //     name: Name {
    //         name: "John",
    //     },
    //     age: Age {
    //         age: 30,
    //     },
    // }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5c394a0255351004cb7683748ad42f64)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a pretty unusual way to deserialize a JSON. Curios what makes you want to have such structs.

The simplest approach should be one of the following:

- Just parse the JSON string into a [`Value`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/serde_json/value/enum.Value.html) instance and take it from there;
- As PitaJ suggests, use a third struct with `#[serde(flatten)]`.

In case you want to have a lot more such structs that have a single property with the same name each, you could write a macro or a custom deserializer.

As a side node, having lowercase struct names is possible but not idiomatic in Rust.

Comment: Well the JSON I am working with is actually more complex and nested, with different group of data that I want to send to different systems. But this question really is more about learning than solving an immediate problem. I edited the spelling. And will make some tests with the Value. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @at54321, here is a way to do it using Value:

```
use std::fmt;
use std::fs::File;
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Name {
    name: String
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Age {
    age: u32
}

fn main() {

    let file = File::open("person.json").unwrap();
    let value: serde_json::Value = serde_json::from_reader(file).unwrap();
    let name= Name {
        name: serde_json::from_value(value["name"].clone()).unwrap()
    };
    let age = Age {
        age: serde_json::from_value(value["age"].clone()).unwrap()
    };
}
```